# Ag grid group by complex object link

Tags: javascript, grouping, ag-grid

Due to some requirements I need to render in ag grid links in some columns. I am able to do it using cellRenderer but when the grouping is used I have only access to string not whole object.
At the moment I am using this code for rendering but I would like to somehow render proper link in if as well.
Now I have:

```
function cellRenderer(params) {
  if (params.node.group) {
    return params.value;
  }

  return '<a href=' + params.value.code + '>' + params.value.name + '</a>';
}
```

But I would like to have something like that but its not working:

```
function cellRenderer(params) {
  return '<a href=' + params.value.code + '>' + params.value.name + '</a>';
}
```

[Example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/plunk/Uv3Y7iI3DaUafdpi)

So no way to render proper link for grouping cell. Anyone has solution to that?

Comment: Grouping is available only in the enterprise version of ag-grid. @Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render HTML content on the Auto Group Column, the easiest option is to provide an `innerRenderer` to the `autoGroupColumnDef`:

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
    minWidth: 200,
    cellRendererParams: {
      innerRenderer: cellRenderer,
    },
  }
```

I'm reusing the cellRenderer you've defined, however it can be anything.

Inside the cellRenderer, we can get the complex object for a grouped row by getting one of it's children, and from there extracting the complex object:

```
if (params.node.group) {
    const country = params.node.allLeafChildren[0].data.country;
    return '<a href=' + country.code + '>' + country.name + '</a>';
  }
```

I've modified the example to remove the `valueGetter` and instead modified the data from the HTTP request to have a complex object for country, this way we have data that contains complex objects that is coming into the grid.

Please see the example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/H9P2tXJxdzHoV3KA

Answer (score 0):

Hello for [grouping cell](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/group-cell-renderer/) [row grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grouping/)

you'd want to config your code the following way

```js
columnDefs:[
  {
  field: 'country',
  cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer', // key for group cell render
  cellRendererParams: {
    innerRenderer: 'myCellRenderer'
  },
  minWidth: 200,
},
{ field: 'year', minWidth: 200, },
  ],
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
    headerName: 'Group',
    minWidth: 200,
  },
  components: {
     myCellRenderer: myGroupCellRenderer(),
  },

...
// replace your getSimpleCellRenderer with the following to access your params and adjust your logic to your criteria and render to your needs

  function myGroupCellRenderer() {
    function MyGroupCellRenderer() {}
    MyGroupCellRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
      const {name, code} = countryValueGetter(params)
      const el = document.createElement("SPAN");
     

  if (params.node.group) {

// we have acccess to the whole object here, group by country and then check the logs
    console.log('params in If', params)
    el.innerHTML = '<a href=' + code + '>' + name + '</a>'
  }


 else {
        // and here
        console.log('params in Else', params)
        el.innerHTML = '<a href=' + code + '>' + name + '</a>'
      } 

   

  
this.eGui = el;
    };

    MyGroupCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function () {
      return this.eGui;
    };

    return MyGroupCellRenderer;
  }
```

[new plnkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/QG7JYdEuhu02zJV8?preview)

Comment: Ok, so where is the link after I have grouped by the country?

Comment: try new plnkr link

Comment: Hmm, nothing has changed

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question then. At the moment what I provided groups by country or year and displays the links with the proper codes e.g UN etc.
Grouping and displaying links is what you want correct?

Comment: Yes, when you have just rows you can see that country has link in the column. But when you group by country I don't know how to get whole country object to properly display link for the group column.

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik you have access to the whole country object within the if or else. I made a plnkr update to demonstrate to you can have links within the group columns. You'll be able to see your name and internal id's for your real data. Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly as I have mentioned in the comment to the answer above it is just example data. There is no such patter in real life code :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cellRenderer(params) {
  if (params.node.group) {
    var countryCode = params.value.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
    return '<a href=' + countryCode + '>' + params.value + '</a>';
  }

  return '<a href=' + params.value.code + '>' + params.value.name + '</a>';
}
```

Here working [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/bVCCDVvqt5YOxi7X)

Comment: Sadly data are just example.....  There is no rule how to parse string into code. In real data I have name and internal id.